# ASP.NET: Adding a parameter to the route stops BeginForm from having Action

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have a project which requires a new parameter to be added to one of the actions. When I add the param to the route, the project stops working.

This is what it looks like when it works.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName", id1 = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional, id3 = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Then I add the new parameter, id4, and the project breaks.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}/{id4}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName", id1 = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional, id3 = UrlParameter.Optional, id4 = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I am using the url http://localhost:58481/ControllerName/ActionName/1234567/123456789.

The action of my form now has no value. If I take the id4 out, the form attribute action value returns.

**EDIT 1**

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "sky-form" }))
    {
        //more markup and code in here
    }
</div>
```

SOURCE

```
<div class="row">
    <form class="sky-form" action="" method="post">
        <!-- More Markup and Code Here -->
    </form>
</div>
```

Action

```
public ActionResult MyAction(AClass view)
{
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching the net, I found a solution is to add a new route to the specific action. If anyone has a better solution please write it down for those seeking :)